# Wrong coefficients in a polynomial fit

Tags: r, curve-fitting, numerics

I am trying to fit data to a fourth-degree polynomial. I tried this in multiple programs (R, Origin Pro, SigmaPlot), all of which give me a polynomial of the form
$ 40000 -2000x + 40x^2 -0.3x^3 + 0.001x^4 $. This doesn't fit the data at all (the y-intercept should be close to zero). All data points are relatively near each other. However, when the programs graphically show the fitted polynomial, it looks like this:
[image: Graphical output of regression]
The shown polynomial clearly fits the data quite well and is (!) distinct from the one given above. For example, the y-intercepts don't match at all. Is there something about regression I don't understand or why do all of the programs plot a different polynomial than they return? Could this be an overflow problem?

Comment: That curve looks to be plotting about the equation you gave. Why do you say your equation doesn’t fit the data?  You have a very high $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$.

Comment: Please explain further, what the different program's results were and what about them does not fit the data. I see data values between 66 and 98. Outside of that range, and that does include the intercept, a polynomial can do whatever it wants. If you insist on the intercept being zero, then either add the point (0, 0) to your data points or tell your software to find a solution w/o intercept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The shown polynomial clearly fits the data quite well and is (!) distinct from the one given above. For example, the y-intercepts don't match at all. Is there something about regression I don't understand or why do all of the programs plot a different polynomial than they return?

#### Round off errors

The polynomial that they return has coefficients that are rounded off (for display). It is not the polynomial that they use in processing (which uses the full precision).

When I look at the fitted values I do not see why the curve and presented polynomial would not have a y-intercept close to zero.

The y-intercept value of the returned polynomial, taken at x=63 (at least that's where the y-axis crosses in this image), is -36:

$$40992.96617 - 2125.34077 \cdot 63 + 40.79366 \cdot 63^2 - 0.34353 \cdot 63^3  + 0.00107 \cdot 63^4 \approx -36$$

**But,** that's a reasonably close y-intercept. The roundoff errors in the returned polynomial are gonna give huge effect because these powers of X are very large.

For example, when the last coefficient is 0.001074 instead of 0.00107 then this adds $0.000004* 63^4 \approx 63$ to the value of the intercept with the y-axis at x=63.

#### Solution

To solve your problem: When you rescale $X$ before the fitting then the roundoff errors in the coefficents will have smller effects. Also you could look into the software how to obtain the returned polynomial with coefficients that have a higher precision.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "roundoff errors"?  The difference between $-36$ and $0$ cannot be explained by floating point imprecision: it's far too large for that.  The "intercept" in the question appears to refer to the value of 40993, as indicated in the image legend.

Comment: @whuber I've made an update. The floating-point precision seems to be sufficient to me to explain differences.

Comment: That's just not true: you won't lose all your precision when working with eight-digit numbers to 15 decimal places.

Comment: @whuber the box in the graph gives the coefficient as 0.00107 and in the question a coefficient of 0.001 is used. Those give roundoff errors. Indeed when the full precision is used then there won't be much error. That's probably why the plotted curve is not wrong.

Comment: I see--by "roundoff error" you mean *limited precision in the display of statistics.*  I think you are focusing on a pure coincidence, because there does not appear to be anything in the original that supposes the "intercept" is the fitted value at the minimum abscissa of the plot.

Comment: @whuber, if the OP has a problem with the estimated intercept being 40k instead of zero then he/she/they has a big problem (or maybe not because we shouldn't expect the intercept value to be very precise). I indeed suspect that the issue is about the intercept at x=63 in which case the issue seems to be about rounding off the values of the coefficients.

Comment: Yes, they have a big problem!  That's exactly the issue: you cannot hope that a polynomial fit will be at all well-behaved for values far from any of the observations; and if you force it through the origin, you can expect the fit to the actual data to be poor.

Comment: @whuber I have added the last paragraph of the question in my answer, because that seems to pinpoint an important cause for the problem. the OP/author seems to believe that the the polynomial provided does not fit the points, while the fitted curve seems to fit it. In my opinion this all seems to stem from the rounding-off errors. The plotted polynomial is not in contradiction with the provided coefficients, and they only differ in the precision.

Comment: Yes, it were round-off  errors! Changing the floating-point precision of the output of the coefficients to a higher precision fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

First, the coefficients in your graph are very close to the ones in your text. So it's not clear why you say

> and is (!) distinct from the one given above

It isn't.

In particular, you write that

> the y-intercept should be close to zero

No, it shouldn't. The y-intercept in your figure is 40993 and in your formula it is 40,000. The problem is that your graph does not show the y intercept at all. It shows that y will be close to 0 when X is about 65.

Then you ask

> Is there something about regression I don't understand or why do all
>   of the programs plot a different polynomial than they return?

There may be something about regression that you don't understand - it's a huge topic - but this question is not evidence of such misunderstanding (but see below). You have simply misinterpreted the output.  And ... the programs do plot the polynomial they return.

Finally, you ask if this is an overflow problem. No. It isn't.

You could try graphing this with a lower limit of 0 for X. That will show one thing you may not have considered which is the danger of extrapolation (I don't know if you intend to extrapolate).

Another potential problem is that your x values are clumped. If you tell us what X and Y are, then we might be able to help more with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the coefficients given by the program were not displayed in full precision. This caused a round-off error which caused the polynomial given by the equation and the polynomial given in the graphic to deviate.